# Contracted version of "isomorphic"

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Had a look around and I can't find a word which acts as a contraction for "isomorphic" in the same way that "monic/epic" is a contraction of "monomorphic/epimorphic". For some reason this strikes me as strange, considering that, at least in Awodey's text, iso is used as often as mono or epi.

Is there a contraction? Something like "isoic" or "isonic", perhaps? 
I suppose there is the risk of confusion by saying a map is "isomorphic" rather than "an isomorphism", but surely in context it would be clear what is meant.

Comment: I've seen "isic". I wish I hadn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although there's a distinction between the noun and adjective abbreviations of *monomorphism* and *epimorphism* (*mono* vs. *monic* and *epi* vs. *epic*), it's fairly common to use *iso* for both the noun and adjective abbreviation of *isomorphism*.

For example, both of these seem normal to me:

- $\mathcal{C}$ is a balanced category if every morphism $f$ of $\mathcal{C}$ which is both a mono and an epi is an iso;
- $\mathcal{C}$ is a balanced category if every morphism $f$ of $\mathcal{C}$ which is both monic and epic is iso.

I've certainly never seen *isoic* or *isonic* used, but I must say I like both of those as words!

Comment: Huh, fair enough I suppose, and yeah it does have a slight ring to it, isonic but more syllables, I guess

Comment: I've never seen "iso" used as an adjective.  An adjective form of "isomorphism" would be "invertible".

Comment: I've seen "iso" as an adjective. Probably only in course notes, e-mails or something like that.